# Should I use bindParam for a query that has no user input?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm fairly new and have been taught that the key rational for prepared queries is safety.

I have a query in my program that receives no user input - it's all using internal variables.  Are there still material benefits to using `bindParam` in a PDO query rather than simply submitting the query string as is?

Comment: Code readability could be the one that comes to mind.

Comment: i guess it is still good practice

Comment: You need to explain your concept of "internal variables". If it's all fixed values, there's no point in preparing queries. If it's refurbished values that came from querying existing database content, well then there might be room for second order SQL woes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if a future update changed the variable so that it became assigned from user input, but noone bothered to alter the query?

One should avoid *ever* concatenating variables into SQL and *always* send them to the RDBMS as parameters.